# how can I update a simple_form checkbox value without submit button in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I update gender field which is a boolean, without a submit button?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@member, remote: :true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :gender %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to achieve that

```
$('#member_gender').change(function(){
  $(this).form.submit();
});
```